# How to show images using recycle view and picasso in android/ java?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I am having trouble showing images that I collected from a website into a recycle view. I first got the image urls using jsoup. Then I added the urls in a list called imgURLS. Now I want to show those images in gridview that has recycle view. The code I have no errors but the images are not showen when I run my android project. Its just blank. Here is some of my code

MAINACTIVITY.JAVA

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new URLcollector().execute();
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    //setBKG = findViewById(R.id.setBKG);
    rvMain = findViewById(R.id.rvMain);

    // can add another parameter here like text
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(imgURLS);
    rvMain.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2));
    rvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

then still in mainactivity.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    // String[] companyList;
    List<String> logoList;
    ImageView currentView;
    Bitmap imgBitmaps;

    public MyAdapter( List<String> logoList) {
        // this.companyList = companyList;
        this.logoList = logoList;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

     @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // load image from picasso and then

        Context context = holder.logo.getContext(); //<----- Add this line

        Picasso.with(context).load(imgURLS.get(position)).into(holder.logo);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return logoList.size();
    }
}
```

My questions are

1) Am I using Picasso correctly?

2) Why did I not be able to see the images(keep in mind visible is on in xml)?

Let me know if I need to provide more of my code.

Comment: Try to open your url in browser. Is it show your image?

Comment: What is this "ImageView currentView;"
Just set in .into(holder.yourImageView) Something like this.

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii yes it is.

Comment: @EugneTroyanskii I updated the .into(holder.logo). But still it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // load image from picasso and then pass it to set Image
    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(logoList.get(position))
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // optional
            .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) //if error
            .into(holder.logo);
    holder.logo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is: " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    // holder.name.setText(companyList[position]);
}
```

If your url is correct. try something like this and don't forget to set INTERNT permission in Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: I did this and still nothing.